# Archiving library for bada

Tags: bada

Can anyone suggest me a file archiving library for bada?

I've looked at minizip (which uses zlib) and bzip2, but they both use Linux or Windows headers for file access, which the bada SDK does not provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this, I managed to use [LiteZip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/LiteZip.aspx) with only minimal modifications.

Comment: thanks for you answer, can you explain it a little more? What changes did you do?

thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I remember that library was using a header that's not available on bada for just a single task that I really didn't need. I think it was something to do with folders and I only needed the library to work with a single file. Anyway, one of the includes should cause an error - delete that include and you will get a few errors in a function that you may simply delete from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use namespace `Osp::Base::Utility` sub-namespace you will find these classes (according to bada 2.0):

```
Osp::Base::Utility::Deflator

Osp::Base::Utility::FileUnzipper

Osp::Base::Utility::FileZipper

Osp::Base::Utility::Inflator

Osp::Base::Utility::ZipEntry
```